# SQL: Multiple addresses present for single person. Select current address if present otherwise select permanent address

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have this scenario and if person have current address present then need to select that address otherwise select permanent address.

I don't want to join `Address` table twice with `Person` as it will impact on performance.

Person

```
| person_id | name  | surname
+-----------+-------+----------
| 10        | ABC10 | XYZ10
| 11        | ABC11 | XYZ11
| 12        | ABC12 | XYZ12
| 13        | ABC13 | XYZ13
```

Address

```
| ID    | person_id | type      | address   | city
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------
| 1     | 10        | Permanent | addr 10P  | city 10P
| 2     | 10        | Current   | addr 10C  | city 10C
| 3     | 11        | Permanent | addr 11P  | city 11P
| 4     | 12        | Permanent | addr 12P  | city 12P
| 5     | 12        | Current   | addr 12C  | city 12C
| 6     | 13        | Permanent | addr 13P  | city 13P
```

Expected output:

```
| person_id | name  | surname   | type      | address   | city
+-----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
| 10        | ABC10 | XYZ10     | Current   | addr 10C  | city 10C
| 11        | ABC11 | XYZ11     | Permanent | addr 11P  | city 11P
| 12        | ABC12 | XYZ12     | Current   | addr 12C  | city 12C
| 13        | ABC13 | XYZ13     | Permanent | addr 13P  | city 13P
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a lateral join and a fetch clause:

```
select p.*, a.type, a.address, a.city
from person p
cross apply (
    select a.*
    from address a
    where a.person_id = p.person_id
    order by case a.type when 'Current' then 1 else 2 end
    fetch first row only
) a
```

You can also use window functions (this will work in all Oracle versions):

```
select p.*, a.type, a.address, a.city
from person p
inner join (
    select a.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by person_id order by case type when 'Current' then 1 else 2 end) as rn
    from address a
) a on a.person_id = p.person_id
where a.rn = 1
```

The `case` expression makes it easy to extend the prioritization logic with more possible address types. If you have just two values, "Permanent" and "Current", then it can be simplified in both queries to: `order by type` (this puts "Current" first).

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this using window functions:

```
select p.*, a.type, a.address, a.city
from person p join
     (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a.person_id order by a.type) as seqnum
      from address a
     ) a
     on a.person_id = p.person_id and a.seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  This assumes that the type is only "current" and "permanent", so it uses string ordering to select "current".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row_number` or `rank` or `dense_rank` function according to your requirement.

Approach using `row_number` is as follows:

```
select * from
(select p.*, a.type, a.address, a.city,
        row_number() over (partition by a.person_id order by a.type) as rn
   from person p join address a
     on a.person_id = p.person_id
) where rn = 1;
```